# C# Datatable woes

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datatable

I have a database command that populates a DataTable I want to get the value of an entry in the Datatable, based on, A: The numeral index of the row, and b, the string name of the column. That's all I want, how is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yourDatatable.Rows[rowIndex]["columnName"]` should work

Answer (score 1):

```
myTbl.Rows[0]["b"];
```

`A` is not a row index.

Comment: I meant A as a list from A to B. LIke, prerequisite A, B, C, so on. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = GetData();
var result = dt.Rows[RowIndex]["MyColumnName"];
```

The `RowIndex` is an indexed property of the datatable which returns a `DataRow`. "MyColumnName" is an indexed property of the DataRow, returning the value as an object.